# Deploy Laravel project to shared hosting without SSH

Tags: php, laravel-5, ssh, ftp, web-deployment

I got my Laravel project ready to be deployed but every free hosting website I tried doesn't have SSH Command Line.

This is what I've tried:

- FTP Upload including .env - Problem is I can't generate a key without command line.
- FTP Upload after installing Softaculous Laravel App - Can't edit or find .env file even when forcing FileZilla to show hidden files.
- FTP Upload and install PHP Shell - Banned from the host

Any suggestions?

Comment: Choose a host with SSH?

Comment: Can't find any free hosts with SSH

Comment: [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/free/), [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) do free VPS for a year on their micro plans.

Comment: They require a credit card just like Azure. Since I'm a student I don't have it.

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: In the first case I get the "No Application Key has been specified" error